# How to display PHP variables in my upload successful html?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple upload_form.php. The first part is PHP. Where the PHP ends is html, the success message

It gets a student's name, student number, email and any message. It also uploads a file, an essay.

The first part has these variables:

```
$q1 = $_POST['cn'];
$q2 = $_POST['sn'];
$q3 = $_POST['email'];
$q4 = $_POST['message'];
```

PHP writes these to a text file and saves them under the student number, which is unique.

The next part uploads the file ok, I won't bore you with that. After the PHP there is some html, to display a nice success message and some links.

In the html I display the date and time (they always say, "But I submitted on time!" They can take a photo of this to show me.):

```
<div> <h1>The date and time now is:</h1>  </div><br>
<div id="div-date"<div>   </div><br>>  </div><br>
```

I would also like to write $q1 and $q2, which are the student's Chinese name and student number, in a div id="name-number" below this

I don't know how to get the PHP variables to display within the html part, as nicely formatted 'html variables'. I can't just write $q1 $q2!

I would be very grateful, as a rank amateur, for any tips!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Make sure your file has extension (.php) 2. Call the php variable: <?php echo $q1; ?>

Comment: Thanks! That's what I have: upload1file2v3.php deals with my data. The html is uploadessayv1.html which calls  the php file when the student clicks send. Works great, thanks to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can echo the variables inside your html section (if these are accessible within the same code section ofc). For example:

```
<div> CN: <?=$q1;?> </div>
```

or full out

```
<div> CN: <?php echo $q1; ?> </div>
```